# Significado do termo "Layout Fluido"

Tags: html, css, css3

Em pesquisas, eu me deparei com uma série de artigos falando de `Design fluido`.Porém a maioria sem explicações claras.

Quero saber o que significa isso no desenvolvimento `Frontend`?

Comment: Resumindo o responsivo contem "fluido", pois tambem pode trabalhar com porcentagem, mas tem limitadores para definir colunas ou blocos (1 por linha), já o fluido é algo fixo mas que ajusta com porcentagem.

Answer (score 2):

É parecido com o responsivo, porém no fluído a adaptação ocorre automaticamente, pois usa medidas relativas em porcentagem para definir o tamanho.

Veja mais em: [Layout Fluído ou Responsivo](https://www.turbosite.com.br/blog/layout-fluido-ou-responsivo/)

Answer (score 2):

A grosso modo, no fluído é a ajustado apenas a "%" dos elementos, mas eles continuam com a mesma estrutura, já no responsivo os elementos podem ser amplamente reorganizados para se adaptar a tela em que serão exibidos, para isso você pode utilizar N frameworks que agilizam o desenvolvimento nesse padrão.

Answer (score 2):

Fluido: Eu não defino tamanho em pixel e sim em porcentagem.

Quando usar? depende.. layout fluido é apenas um dos complementos para um bom layout.

Eu costumo trabalhar na mesma pagina com Layout fixo, fluido e reponsivo.

Por exemplo, o container deixo fixo, suas colunas fluidas, e quando se quebra o layout vou ajustando a responsividade.

Comment: Você adota isso como padrão, ou em apenas alguns casos, porque pelo que vi nas outras respostas eu consigo resolver todos os problemas com layout Fluido. Ou não é bem assim?

Comment: @RenanCarlos eu te diria que você não resolve tudo com layout fluido, por exemplo em uma tela full hd 100% seria muito não concorda? então eu limitaria o tamanho para uns 1300px, ou se temos 10 colunas de 10% em um smartphone seria muito pouco não concorda? o ideal em minha  opinião é saber trabalhar com layout fixo, fluido e responsivo juntos adequando-se ao problema